# finding values from a list of dictionaries where dicts have different amounts of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, select

I have a list of dictionaries with different amounts of keys/values, I cant change the list because its extracted from another program over which I have no control:

```
l = [{'a': 123, 'b': 234, 'c': 'approved'}, {'a': 456, 'b': 567}, {'a': 678, 'b': 789, 'c': 'approved'}]
```

I want to get a list of values for key 'a' where the key 'c' == 'approved', if I try:

```
approved_list = [i['a'] for i in l if i['c'] == 'approved']
```

I get the error: `KeyError: 'c'`  I assume because dict[1] has no key 'c'.

I tried to get the list of dictionaries to only include those with key 'c' like this:

```
dicts_with_approval = [i for i in l if i.keys() == 'c']
```

but that just gives an empty list [].

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` instead to provide a value if the key lookup fails:

```
[i['a'] for i in l if i.get('c') == 'approved']
# [123, 678]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your answer like this (check whether "c" is in the `keys` of the `dict`:

```
approved_list = [i['a'] for i in l if "c" in i.keys() if i['c'] == 'approved' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach here is slightly incorrect

```
[i for i in l if i.keys() == 'c']
```

You are trying to check if the list which is `i.keys()` is equal to a single key element `c` which will never be true. Therefore, it should be other way round, you need to check if the key `c` is present in the dictionary `i.keys()`.

Change to your existing code

```
[i['a'] for i in l if 'c' in i.keys() and 'approved'==i['c']] # [123, 678]
```